# Creating libraries for Arduino

Tags: c++, c, ide, arduino

I want to write a library for my Arduino(header and class files), but I don't know what tools to use for this job and how to test and debug them.

The Arduino IDE just helps in writing plain programs for direct bootloading, not full project management thing (correct me if I am wrong and guide appropriately with relevant references).

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler supports the `#include` directive, you can write your library, then `#include` it. This is expanded on [in this tutorial about writing libraries for the Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial).

Answer (score 4):

For testing you can use [ArduinoUnit](http://code.google.com/p/arduinounit/downloads/list). This itself is a library - so take a look at the source code (in the download) if you need inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Just take any Arduino library and look inside. You'll find all what it needs to make one – the class, public and private variables and methods, maybe getters, setters...